# about regex, you find {else} and allow nested

Tags: php, regex

I created this pattern: `{if ([^}]*)}((?:[\w\s]+[^}]*)){\/if}`

but I have done a long time ago now, the pattern is, for example:

```
{if $module=admin}

{/if}
```

but I want to find:

```
{if $module=admin}

{else}

{/if}
```

as far as possible to find both with the same pattern.

Any ideas? thank you very much :)

Comment: it seems like you're trying to create an expression parser and statement parser but don't know it yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. That it's a regex question is clear from the tag you used, and *thanks* has no business in either the title or text here. If we remove those parts of your title, it is blank. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking, and it should be clear enough to be of use to future readers here who see it in a search result.

Comment: What is the language you are using the regex in, Lucas?

Comment: Try [`{if ([^}]*)}([^{]*(?:{(?!\/if})[^{]*)*){\/if}`](https://regex101.com/r/pK0cJ2/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That would match any {tag}, not specifically. Though the OP is pretty unclear what exactly he needs.

Comment: I use PHP.
Wiktor, is not exactly what I want, however, he says Whothehellisthat what if.

Comment: Write your own  parser or use a ready-made one.

Answer (score 0):

[`/{if ([^}]+)}([\W\w]*?)(?:{else}([\W\w]*?))?{\/if}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/lB8wJ8/2)

- `{if` Literal text.
- `([^}]+)` **If condition**: One or more non-closing-curly-brace (`}`) characters, all captured.
- `}` Literal text.
- `([\W\w]*?)` **Inside If**: Zero or more characters. Match until the next part is found. (Very inefficient; you can rewrite to make this more performant.)
- `(?:{else}([\W\w]*?))?` Optional group.

  - `{else}` **Else**: Literal text.
  - `([\W\w]*?)` **Inside Else**: Zero or more characters. Match until the next part is found. (Very inefficient; you can rewrite to make this more performant.)
- `{\/if}` **Closing**: Literal text.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me. Did you check out the regex101 link at the top? [Here's the same with more data to show it working.](https://regex101.com/r/lB8wJ8/3)

Comment: Well, what I meant is that it is not safe to use (lazy) dot matching patterns in marked up texts. Once there is a nested `if` tag, this expression will stop working.

Comment: That's true, but that's not a problem with my regex, but with using any kind of regex to capture a whole piece of text that could have nested tags as well.

Comment: To me it sounded like this is for a simpler thing, without nesting supported. If it needed nesting, there is no way of doing this in regex, and would need actual parsing of tags, depth, etc.

Comment: Whothehellisthat, it seems to work as I want, thank you.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3e4gk
should mark the "if" that is in the middle so that then when it replaced the missing mark (one by one).
as achieving that? It is that I have several more patterns to which I want to apply this rule to nest.

Comment: Okay. So is it all working, or is there a new bug, or what?

Comment: I could do this based on what you did.
apparent solution: http://regexr.com/3e4gt

edit: wait, I had a mistake, that regex does not have added what the "else"

Comment: Sorry--still confused. Nesting ifs within each other won't work. To do things like that, you'll need to use a completely different approach, including code beyond just the regex. Let me know if you need that or not.

Comment: I really don't understand "#bad". Do you need help with anything?

Comment: "#bad" = "#wrong"
I speak Spanish, and I am using Google translator.
what is "#bad" is wrong.

Comment: Okay. So the code isn't working? What is it you are trying to do with the regex?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3e4h9
See the "#" in the last lines, the pattern should mark rather than those which are marked with "*".

Comment: Are you saying you want it to only match the deepest nested {if} set (with a # in your example)? So the outer ones are ignored, and you only get the inner most {if} (marked with a *)?

Comment: exactly because PHP check again until there is no more to replace.

Comment: It doesn't work like that in JS. Are you sure that's how it works in PHP? Have you tested to make sure?

Comment: you're right, it does not work as I said.
that solution may be for there to be "if" nested?

Comment: Basically, you'll have to actually parse it all. I'll start work on it, but do let me know if that's not a route your want to go down.

Comment: I'm making a template system not to mix php / html. Very equal to "smarty" but more simple and optimal.
Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Okay. You know PHP is basically a templating language to begin with though? What does this special templating give you that PHP doesn't? Just curious.

Comment: for a web designer (spatialized in HTML and CSS) it is not more understandable this: http://pastebin.com/0cPvXRaC
this one: http://pastebin.com/EuM1wiuN
Also, you should imagine that there are many html files and many variables, functions and things to do with php within html.

Comment: create my own system modulation php application, I would like to show it running and you see the code.
The goal is that anyone can create complex applications with basic knowledge, without knowing much about security or other concerns.
Also, my system allows the application to be scalable, secure, easy to create, and so on.
It is efficient and faster to create a complex application with my system :)

Comment: Oh, okay. Interesting. So basically you just want to remove the `load_files` and other function calls? Could you not kind of load things the other way around? So a page would just have a `render_template()` around all the content? That way the designer could just use those if statements as normal.

Comment: Just seems like you're reinventing the wheel in a language that already supports what you need to do. I've still posted another answer for you, but you'll have to code it up yourself.

Comment: I do not understand very well, can you give me an example of what you trying to say?
remember that I do not speak English and use the Google translator.

Comment: what I do is reinventing the wheel in a better way.

Comment: To me, `<?php if($username == 'admin') { ?>` or `{if $username=admin}` look about the same. Just a few extra characters for the PHP version. Personally I don't see the point in writing a whole parsing/rendering/rewriting engine to take out a few letters.

Comment: use "<? php?>" means that the file should be run, use tags like "{$ username}" means that must be replaced.
The second is more suited to my security layer, I see it more safe, efficient and beautiful.
Plus, it's like I said, I like totally separate php code html.

Answer (score 0):

[`/(?:{(?:if ([^}]+)|(else)|(\/if))}|^)([^{]*(?:(?!{(?:if|else|\/if)}){[^{]*)*)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/lB8wJ8/4)

Okay, this is way more complicated than the previous one, so I'll skip the full explanation for now (unless you request it later).

Basically, each match will give you a number of captured strings, in the following order:

- **Tag**: (one of the following)

  - If start's condition (like `$module=admin`).
  - Else start
  - If end
  - Or none of the above.
- **Content**: All content after the captured tag, up to the next special tag.

  - If there was no tag, this means the content that was captured is from the start of the input text up to the first If tag.
  - If the tag was If end, the content is just whatever comes after that specific tag. This could be useful or not, depending on how the input is structured.

This will give you all the pieces you need to implement your special `{if}` tags. I can give you pointers as what things you should think about, but I'll leave the PHP coding to you.

---

HINT: In your code, you can sort of build the structure of the document. For example:

```
[
  { content: "blah blah blah" },
  { if-condition: "module=page",
    content: ["after opening if, before else"],
    else-content: ["after else, before end of if", {
      if-condition: "page=4",
      content: ["nested content"]
    }]
  },
  { content: "end of file" }
]
```

Then you could loop over that and re-render it all however you like.

Comment: You not know how much I appreciate the effort when a person tries to help me but I think is not what I seek, not "lose" more time. Thank you very much for all the help!!

Comment: (Edited post.) Would any of that be useful? This is _the only way_ of finding and using nested tags like this.

Comment: afraid I must insist, I'll see if I can do otherwise. Many thanks :) really.